# 2 UIcollectionview in a scrollable view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a scrollview which will consist 2 UIcollectionviews (shown in the screenshot).
What I want to do is I wish the scrollable view will expand as the 2nd UIcollectionview items increased. So the view can scroll down infinitely when the contents of the UIcollectionview expand.

Can someone guide me on what is the method to do that ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voPDX.png)

Comment: Should the horizontal collectionView stay fix above the vertical one while scrolling or should it scroll with it ?

Comment: @Mindhavok the vertical should scroll with it

Comment: @Mindhavok sorry my typo, the horizontal will need to scroll with the scrollview.

Comment: "Can someone guide me on what is the method to do that with the storyboard and auto layout?" There is no such way. That's not how auto layout works. It isn't magic. As the collection view "expands", you would need to change the content size of the collection view and the scroll view in _code_.

Comment: @matt Noted, then can you guide me on the how to grow the scrollview when the vertical UIcollectionview grows? I will edit the question

Comment: As I said, they are both the same: they are both scroll views, you just change their content size.